# Convert Jupyter Notebook to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

How i can convert jupyter notebook in to pdf file?

I work on some data project which requires to send ready report to clients in `pdf` file. I am missing last part with pdf creation.

I already installed `MikTex`. I used following code but it gives syntax error.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf notebook.ipynb
```

I expect that pdf report will be saved in my folder.

Comment: You can simply save it as HTML and then print the HTML to a PDF file.

Comment: this will do it, with command line :  `jupyter nbconvert --execute --to pdf mynotebook.ipynb`

Comment: what error do you get exactly? You forgot to put it.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: sometimes rebooting might help after install

Comment: I am using windows. I get invalid syntax error for 'jupyter nbconvert --execute --to pdf mynotebook.ipynb'

Comment: @Michal what ended up being your solution?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
File -> Download as -> PDF via LaTeX(.pdf)
```

Comment: Well yes but i would like to do it using a code. Not do it manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

1st install **'texlive-xetex'**
then convert it using **'nbconvert'**

```py
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf test.ipynb
```